# Spring Boot executable jar and external configuration file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that uses 3rd-party jar. This jar requires an xml config file, that must be provided by clients on runtime (individually) and cannot be pre-packaged. 3rd party lib loads that file using below sequence (I stripped `if`s and null-checks):

```
    FileConfigurator.class.getResource("/" + filename);
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/" + filename);
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(filename);
```

I cannot change the way that lib loads the file (e.g. using Spring's Resource loading), so it must be on classpath. Therefore I seem to lose the possibility of executing it like `java -jar my-spring-boot-app.jar`, because `-jar` option prevents any additional classpath entries from being added. So I started running it like

`java -classpath my-spring-boot-app.jar:./config/: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`

My directory structure is following:

```
|-- config
|   |-- application.properties
|   `-- 3rd-party-config.xml
|-- my-spring-boot-app.jar
```

But then Spring's autowiring started to fail: Additional `application.properties` file in config directory overrides some of settings and using above command causes app startup to fail:

> Error creating bean with name 'ORBConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.company.app.communication.corba.orb.ORBConfig.serverName; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'application.corba.serverName' in string value "${application.corba.serverName}"

Field `String serverName` is annotated with `@Value("${application.corba.serverName}")`, the property is defined in `application.properties` file bundled within JAR and value injection works fine when additional `application.properties` is not present in config dir.

My actual question is: what is the advisable way of deploying and/or running Spring Boot application, to take advantage of executable Jar feature, provide additional classpath resources on runtime and still be able to override some (but not all) properties by classpath `application.properties` file?

Application is packaged using spring boot maven plugin and uses `spring-boot-starter-parent` parent POM.

Answer (score 0):

One simple answer if you won't change the startup command:

> move `./config/application.properties` to `./config/config/application.properties`

If there exist more than one classpath resources with same name, Spring Boot will load only one of them, in you case, Spring Boot load and prioritize property resources as following:

1. `file:config/application.properties`
2. `classpath:application.properties` which maybe resolved to either `my-spring-boot-app.jar!/applcation.properties` or `./config/application.properties`

If your classLoader chosen `./config/application.properties` as second property source. Bang!

Spring Boot's default configuration property resource path priority (highest to lowest precedence) is:

1. `file:config/`
2. `file:`
3. `classpath:config/`
4. `classpath`

The ordinary executable jar execution make those two configuration property fall into:

1. `file:config/application.properties`
2. `classpath:application.properties` (from jar)

And moving `./config/application.propertie` to './config/config/application.properties' becomes:

1. `classpath:config/application.properties`
2. `classpath:application.properties` (from jar)

Both in the same order and have no ambiguous.